# JNLP execution fails with message Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javaws"

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am using build file to compile my project. The code compiles successfully and is generating the `.jar` and `.jnlp` file. But when I launch the application i am getting

```
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javaws" 
    (in directory "/sreekanth/ProjectsCXF/JavaWebStartTest/src/build/jar"): 
    java.io.IOException: error=2,No such file or directory.
```

My build file

```
`<!-- Build file for the project. -->
<project basedir="." default="launch" name="OPRS_JNLP">

  <target name="properties">
    <property name="build" value="build" />
    <property name="dist" value="dist" />
    <property name="src" value="src" />

    <property
      name="classpath"
      value="${java.home}/jre/lib/javaws.jar" />
  </target>

  <target
    name="compile"
    depends="properties"
    description="Compile the project" >
    <mkdir dir="${build}/share" />
    <javac
      debug="on"
      destdir="${build}/share"
      srcdir="com/abhibus/oprs"
      source="1.6"
      classpath="${classpath}" />
    <copy todir="${build}/share">
      <fileset dir="com/abhibus/oprs">
        <exclude name="**/CVS" />
        <exclude name="**/*.java" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target
    name="dist"
    depends="compile"
    description="Create project distribution" >
    <mkdir dir="${build}/jar" />
    <mkdir dir="${build}/jar/lib" />
    <jar destfile="${build}/jar/apsrtcoprs.jar">
      <fileset dir="${build}/share">
        <include name="**/*.class" />
      </fileset>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target
    name="make-launch-file"
    depends="properties"
    description="Copies and configures the launch file" >
    <copy todir="${build}/jar" >
      <fileset dir="${src}/conf" >
        <include name="**/*.jnlp" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target
    name="launch"
    depends="dist, make-launch-file"
    description="Launch the project using webstart">
    <exec executable="javaws"
      dir="${build}/jar">
      <arg line="-codebase file:. file:./apsrtcoprs.jnlp" />
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target
    name="uninstall"
    depends="properties"
    description="Uninstall the project from the webstart cache">
    <exec executable="javaws">
      <arg
        line="-uninstall http://localhost:9999/apsrtcoprs.jnlp"
        />
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
    depends="properties"
    description="Clean all generated files">
      <delete dir="${build}" />
      <delete dir="${dist}" />
  </target>
</project>`
```

What is going wrong here? can some one please help me with this?

Comment: How do you launch it? Have you tried from the command line?

Comment: Confirm that you have ${java.home}/bin in your path, that is where javaws executable should reside in. Also, please confirm that it is really is there. Which OS is this run on?

Comment: @eis, which path are you referring to? Is it my project build path ?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, Thank you. Specified the complete path and it's working. :)

Comment: @user1103504 executable path. You can accomplish the same thing with complete path like said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<exec executable="${java.home}/bin/javaws" ..
```

(Or whatever, but..) specify the complete path.